# Heroku image corruption

Tags: thin, corruption

When uploading an image through git to heroku, the image is corrupted when it gets sent from the web server. I've been trying to fix it by going `g rm --cached images/contact-me.png` and then `g add images/contact-me.png` again, and then pushing.

Also;

```
xyz@co-data:~/labs/exposeit-site$ sha1sum images/contact-me.png 
2d319cd64e94afe7cdd169347653670a1dd82581  images/contact-me.png
xyz@co-data:~/labs/exposeit-site$ wget http://exposeit.herokuapp.com/images/contact-me.png
--2012-08-16 16:50:35--  http://exposeit.herokuapp.com/images/contact-me.png
Resolving exposeit.herokuapp.com (exposeit.herokuapp.com)... 50.19.121.246, 174.129.192.155, 184.73.155.93, ...
Connecting to exposeit.herokuapp.com (exposeit.herokuapp.com)|50.19.121.246|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1230115 (1.2M) [image/png]
Saving to: `contact-me.png'

100%[=================================================================================>] 1,230,115    963K/s   in 1.2s    

2012-08-16 16:50:36 (963 KB/s) - `contact-me.png' saved [1230115/1230115]

xyz@co-data:~/labs/exposeit-site$ sha1sum contact-me.png 
74d97745d35bb67e5517611b683ed461bd0c1686  contact-me.png
```

and

```
xyz@co-data:~/labs/exposeit-site$ g ls-files | grep contact-me
images/contact-me.png
```

Is this a problem of Heroku's?

**Update**:

Procfile:

```
web:  bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RACK_ENV -p $PORT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer is that the `thin` gem has a bug that takes string length instead of length of the byte array that is the underlying image. Why it would first be converted to a string, I don't know.

The solution is to add, to your Gemfile:

```
 gem 'rack-jekyll', :git => 'https://github.com/adaoraul/rack-jekyll.git', :require => 'rack/jekyll'
```

...and it will be downloaded from github rather than RubyGems.

Answer (score 1):

Weird. Still, you look okay to me. http://exposeit.herokuapp.com/images/contact-me.png

Is best to host images and static content elsewhere rather than put megabytes in source control  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Comment: When I request that file, the shoes have been cut off. Since we're just testing Heroku right now (meaning, we're not that invested in it yet), we're not into hosting them on S3 right now. Also, these images aren't static, but may be changed between commits as I do both coding and graphics...

Comment: You could test whether the image was corrupted during the upload by running `sha1sum` on the server https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssh-access

Comment: If you run your app locally with `foreman start`, do you get the same issue?

Comment: Indeed, I had been using the jekyll and nginx servers to test, but it seems like thin has the same behaviour locally *dang*... Now what...?

Comment: Here's a guy with my same problem http://mikemayo.org/2012/deploying-jekyll-sites-to-heroku-with-rack-jekyll/

Comment: "Turned out that the old version was reading in the file, turning the body into a string, calling .length off that string, and passing that as the content length. " <-- that's a daily wtf right there.